# How to union two ordered queries in the same table

Tags: mysql

I have events table with columns
'title',
'description',
'start_date',
'end_date'.

I want to get ordered list live and future  events, depends on 'start_date' and 'end_date'.

I try

```
(
    select * 
    from `events`
    where `start_date` < NOW() and `end_date` > NOW() 
    order by `start_date` desc
) 
union all
(
    select * 
    from `events`
    where `start_date` > NOW() 
    order by `start_date` desc)
```

but result have not that ordering which I want. I want at first ordered list by start_date live events after that ordered list by start_date future events.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * from (
(
    select start_date, end_date, 'Live' as event_type
    from `events`
    where `start_date` < NOW() and `end_date` > NOW() 
) 
union
(
    select start_date, end_date, 'Future' as event_type
    from `events`
    where `start_date` > NOW() ) ) a
ORDER BY event_type desc
, case when event_type = 'Live' then start_date end desc
, case when event_type = 'Future' then start_date end asc;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is what I want.

Comment: Great! Keep in mind that it doesn't do any good to have `ORDER BY` inside of what you are unioning, because it will essentially be ignored. You have to do any ordering on the results of the union.

Answer (score 2):

I think you do not need union in this one.
Just put a `OR` condition in your basic query.

Then, to split the result into `"this one is live"` and `"this one is future"` you can use a flag

```
SELECT *, start_date < NOW() AS flag 
FROM `events`
WHERE (`start_date` < NOW() and `end_date` > NOW()) 
   OR `start_date` > NOW()
ORDER BY flag DESC, start_date
```

Nota : the `DESC` is here to show you you want live before future event. Otherwise just put `ASC`.

Comment: Wouldn't we want the `flag` to be sorted in descending order so that live events are first?

Comment: @AcatnamedMidnight, artragis, thanks for yours answers. Both are work.   But I have one more question, how can I get the same result but in this time I want order live events by 'desc', and future events by 'asc'.

Comment: See my updated answer. You can apply the same `CASE` statement in an `ORDER` clause idea to either mine or @artragis answer.

Comment: your `ORDER BY` can look like `ORDER BY flag DESC, start_date ASC`

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just select  all events ordered by `start_date`?

```
select * 
from `events`
where (`start_date` < NOW() AND `end_date` > NOW())
or (`start_date` > NOW())
order by `start_date` desc
```

Anyway live events will be first, then future events

Comment: This is not what i want. Because I first want to get ordered list of live events (where `start_date` < NOW() and `end_date` > NOW() ), and after future events (  where `start_date` > NOW() ).

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the query, now it should be what and you want
1) select ALL (live OR future) events
2) order by `start_date`
Live events will be first, future events seconds, because live events have `start_date`<NOW() and future events have `start_date`>NOW()